# AlertDialog Does Not Work After Dismiss / Cancel is called?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I have an AlertDialog with 3 radio buttons.The alert is shown when a button is clicked.

I call `dialog.dismiss();` when a radio button is selected by the user in the AlertDialog. Here "dialog" is from
  `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {`

Now the issue is that I cannot seem to pop up the Alert again after an item has been selected. Suprisingly, on a screen rotation everything seems to work fine again!

I also get the same results (i.e it does not work) when I replace `dialog.dismiss();` with `dialog.cancel();`

Please advice!

Comment: Please post the whole activity if you could.  Seems like the problem would be how and where you're initializing the dialog.

Comment: Hi Sberg! Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, it was a very fix based on your input. I was just calling it at the wrong place. If you can repost your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it since it did help out.Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the whole activity if you could. Seems like the problem would be how and where you're initializing the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Sberg! Like I said earlier, it was a very easy fix based on your input. I was just calling it at the wrong place. :)